# TinyMCE - how to make toolbar expanded by default

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

I am having TinyMCE-6 with the following toolbar options:

```
    menubar: false,
    plugins: ['searchreplace', 'link', 'anchor', 'image', 'table', 'charmap','fullscreen','code', 'preview',
    'lists','help','wordcount'],
    toolbar: 'cut copy paste pastetext | undo redo | searchreplace | selectall | link unlink anchor | ' +
    'image| table | hr| charmap  |fullscreen | code | preview print | ' +
    'bold italic underline strikethrough subscript superscript | removeformat |'+
    'numlist bullist | outdent indent | blockquote |alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify |'+
    'blocks fontfamily fontsize | forecolor backcolor|help |' +
    '',
```

When it is rendered in a page, all the toolbars are not shown by default. [image]

I have to click on the 3 dots on the right to expand the whole toolbar. [image]

**Is it possible to have all the toolbar expanded by default while loading tinyMCE ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make use of **toolbar_mode** configuration in TinyMCE

```
toolbar_mode :'wrap',
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/toolbar-configuration-options/#wrap

Working example - https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/duiaab/1

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with an API call you add to your TinyMCE configuration.

The TinyMCE command to use is `ToggleToolbarDrawer`.  You can use the setup function in your TinyMCE init to call this API:

```
tinymce.init({
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function (e) {
      editor.execCommand('ToggleToolbarDrawer')
    });
  }
  ...
});
```

Here is a working example:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/skiaab